# Kaldi on Android - Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :speechutils:app.?

Tags: java, android, kaldi

Trying use a speechRecognition technology, got recommendation for Kaldi but Failed to find no android Studio project solely on this. Hope someone can recommend a android studio project on this.

---

Using [this](https://github.com/Kaljurand/K6nele) and it has no gradle wrapper?

Also after running with local gradle distribution, it gives following error :

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :speechutils:app.
```

- and more similar error.

> How can I solve this?

---

note - this may seem discussion based etc but this is not and hoping for some constructive advice.

---